# Hibernate save to file

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Is there a way to use Hibernate to write the rows to a file instead of the DB?
So inserts to 2 tables T1, T2 would be 2 rows added to 2 files T1.csv, T2.csv
Plan is to write to file and then bulk load that file into the db at end of day.

Answer (score 0):

I would say hibernate is use for object-relational mapping. If you are saving to file, its not really object you are working with.

You should consider JDBC with spring. There is a nice [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-excel-file-via-abstractjexcelview/) on it

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but it might help you: [CSV file JDBC driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csvjdbc/) I think it's can be configured towork with hibernate. [Some example of usage.](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks. That looks likea nice tool but its read-only. Im interested in writes